# How to exclude imports from automodapi output?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, astropy

I am trying to use [automodapi](http://sphinx-automodapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate documentation for my Django project. When I call automodapi like this:

```
.. automodapi:: mypackage.mymodule
```

the output includes all imported classes and functions, e.g, the Django Model class, in the index of Functions and Classes. I would like to exclude the imports and only list those classes and functions declared in the module I specified.

I couldn't see anything about this in the documentation.

Is there a way to do this, preferably without modifying modules?

UPDATE: @saimn has provided a working solution using `__all__` but my project doesn't use `__all__`. It would be nice if there was a solution that didn't involve modifying the modules.

Comment: Did you see the answer by jmm? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68984608/3154588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__all__` variable (this should probably be stated more clearly in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm this works for classes and functions but not for variables (which admittedly I didn't mention in my comment) when the `:include-all-objects:` is used.

Comment: A follow up: my modules currently don't employ `__all__` so it would be nice if there was a way of doing this without modifying my module. I tried the `:allowed-package-names:` option but this didn't seem to work as described (with Sphinx 1.6.5, Automodapi 0.6)

Comment: Apologies, my first comment was incorrect - this solution also works for variables.

Answer (score 2):

Patching `automodapi` to only include locals also addresses this issue while not requiring any changes to your code:

```py
def patch_automodapi(app):
    """Monkey-patch the automodapi extension to exclude imported members"""
    from sphinx_automodapi import automodsumm
    from sphinx_automodapi.utils import find_mod_objs
    automodsumm.find_mod_objs = lambda *args: find_mod_objs(args[0], onlylocals=True)

def setup(app):
    app.connect("builder-inited", patch_automodapi)
```

Source: https://github.com/astropy/sphinx-automodapi/issues/119

The above snippet goes into your `conf.py` sphinx configuration file.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks answering this old question.